Classification of coverages on the category $\mathcal{C} = \left\{ a \overset{f}{\to} b \right\}$
This question is similar to my previous question: Sheaves on sites whose underlying category has only one object and only the identity morphism .
I'm using the definition of site from the Stacks Project: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00VG .
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category consisting of two objects $a$ and $b$ and three morphisms $\operatorname{id}_a$, $\operatorname{id}_b$ and $f: a \to b$.
It is clear that $\operatorname{PSh}(\mathcal{C})$ is just the arrow category of $\mathsf{Set}$.
I would like to understand all possible coverages on $\mathcal{C}$, as well as the categories of sheaves on the resulting sites.
Here's my attempt:
A coverage is given by a family of covers, for each object of $\mathcal{C}$. Hence we have to produce families $C_a \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\{\operatorname{id}_a\})$ and $C_b \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\{\operatorname{id}_b, f\})$. Additionally, by Axiom (1), it is required that $\{\operatorname{id}_a\} \in C_a$ and $\{\operatorname{id}_b\} \in C_b$.
This leaves us with the following $4$ choices:

$\emptyset \in C_a$?

$\emptyset \in C_b$?

$\{f\} \in C_b$?

$\{\operatorname{id}_b, f\} \in C_b$?


We see that we have $16$ candidates for coverages. Let's label the candidates via $4$-tuples of $0$'s and $1$'s.
Let's check which of these candidates fulfills the other axioms for a coverage.
Axiom (2) only gives us a nontrivial requirement if we start with a cover that is neither empty nor just the identity. Here, the nontrivial possible covers are $\{f\}$ and $\{\operatorname{id}_b, f\}$. Axiom (2) now gives us the following implications:

If $\emptyset \in C_a$ and $\{f\} \in C_b$, then $\emptyset \in C_b$

If $\emptyset \in C_b$ and $\{\operatorname{id}_b, f\} \in C_b$, then $\{f\} \in C_b$


This rules out the following candidates: $(1, 0, 1, 0)$, $(1, 0, 1, 1)$, $(0, 1, 0, 1)$ and $(1, 1, 0, 1)$
Axiom (3) is only interesting if we start with a non-identity morphism along which to pull back, i.e. $f$. This now gives us the following implication:

If $\emptyset \in C_b$, then $\emptyset \in C_a$

This rules out the following possibilities: $(0, 1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0, 1)$, $(0, 1, 1, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 1, 1)$.
As far as I can tell, the following sites remain:



Site
$C_a$
$C_b$
Label




$\mathcal{C}_1$
$\{\{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$
$\{\{\operatorname{id}_b\}\}$
$(0, 0, 0, 0)$


$\mathcal{C}_2$
$\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$
$\{\{\operatorname{id}_b\}\}$
$(1, 0, 0, 0)$


$\mathcal{C}_3$
$\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$
$\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_b\}\}$
$(1, 1, 0, 0)$


$\mathcal{C}_4$
$\{\{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$
$\{\{f\}, \{\operatorname{id}_b\}\}$
$(0, 0, 1, 0)$


$\mathcal{C}_5$
$\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$
$\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_b\}, \{f\}\}$
$(1, 1, 1, 0)$


$\mathcal{C}_6$
$\{\{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$
$\{\{\operatorname{id}_b\}, \{\operatorname{id}_b, f\}\}$
$(0, 0, 0, 1)$


$\mathcal{C}_7$
$\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$
$\{\{\operatorname{id}_b\}, \{\operatorname{id}_b, f\}\}$
$(1, 0, 0, 1)$


$\mathcal{C}_8$
$\{\{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$
$\{\{\operatorname{id}_b\}, \{f\}, \{\operatorname{id}_b, f\}\}$
$(0, 0, 1, 1)$


$\mathcal{C}_9$
$\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_a\}\}$
$\{\emptyset, \{\operatorname{id}_b\}, \{f\}, \{\operatorname{id}_b, f\}\}$
$(1, 1, 1, 1)$



My questions are:

Are there really $9$ different coverages on $\mathcal{C}$? Or did I make a mistake somewhere? In particular, I'm unsure whether my list of consequences of Axioms (2) and (3) is exhaustive.

What do the corresponding categories of sheaves $\operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_n)$ for $1 \leq n \leq 9$ look like? What can we say about the inclusion and sheafification functors?



Many of these are saturations of earlier coverages and thus have the same sheaves.

To reinforce the above point, there are only 4 subtoposes of the presheaf topos. As it happens, they correspond to the 4 full subcategories of the underlying category of the site. (In general there will be more subtoposes.)

@ZhenLin I think I found the 4 equivalence classes, but I'm not sure whether I understood the resulting sheaf categories correctly. Could you take a look at it?

Two coverages have the same sheaves iff they generate the same topology.
So let's look at the possible sieves on $a$. They are $\emptyset$ and $\{\operatorname{id}_a\}$. Now let's look at the possible sieves on $b$. They are $\emptyset$, $\{f\}$ and $\{\operatorname{id}_b, f\}$. From this we see that the sites defined in the question fall into the following equivalence classes:

$\mathcal{C}_1$, $\mathcal{C}_6$ with covering sieves for $a$: $\{\operatorname{id}_a\}$ and for $b$: $\{\operatorname{id}_b, f\}$. This is the trivial topology, so we have that $\operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_1) = \operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_6)$ is just the arrow category of $\mathsf{Set}$.

$\mathcal{C}_2$, $\mathcal{C}_7$ with covering sieves for $a$: $\emptyset$, $\{\operatorname{id}_a\}$ and for $b$: $\{\operatorname{id}_b, f\}$. Since $a$ admits an empty cover, we must have that $F(a)$ is a singleton. Then there is a unique function $F(b) \to F(a)$, so we have that $\operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_2) = \operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_7)$ are just $\mathsf{Set}$.

$\mathcal{C}_3$, $\mathcal{C}_5$, $\mathcal{C}_9$ with covering sieves for $a$: $\emptyset$, $\{\operatorname{id}_a\}$ and for $b$: $\emptyset$, $\{f\}$, $\{\operatorname{id}_b, f\}$. Since every object has an empty cover, $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ must be singletons, so we have that $\operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_3) = \operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_5) = \operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_9)$ is just the category with one object and only the identity morphism.

$\mathcal{C}_4$, $\mathcal{C}_8$ with covering sieves for $a$: $\{\operatorname{id}_a\}$ and for $b$: $\{f\}$, $\{\operatorname{id}_b, f\}$. As far as I understand, the sheaf condition implies that in this case, $F(f): F(b) \to F(a)$ is an isomorphism. This means that we again have that $\operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_4) = \operatorname{Sh}(\mathcal{C}_8)$ is just $\mathsf{Set}$.



This is correct AFAICT (except you probably meant "there is a unique function $F(b) \to F(a)$").

@NaimFavier Corrected, thanks
